# newly installed apache serving html content as text

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu-9.04

I am running an Apache instance on Ubuntu and am having this problem:  .HTML files with bonafide HTML inside is being served as a text file:

```
> **For eg. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"> <html>
> <body> <h1>Index to Butterthlies
> Catalogs</h1>
```

etc. etc.**

I checked the header in firebug and sure enough the page is `plain\text`. I figured I'm probably missing the `mod_mime` module, so I tried to include it as a module like this:

```
LoadModule mod_mime /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
TypesConfig conf/mime.types
```

where the `/usr/lib`... path contains the `mod_mime.so`. But this doesn't work and gives the following error:

> Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/www/APACHE3/site.first/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_mime' in file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so: undefined symbol: mod_mime

Answer (score 2):

So long description is useless, last paragraph is enough.

Reinstall your apache from scratch, something is broken in your installation.

BTW, apache installed from package of any distributive should be already configured properly to serve HTML files.

Answer (score 2):

Change the LoadModule line to look like this:

```
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
```